# How to make a custom merge in multiple branchs?

Tags: php, linux, git, git-branch

I have a PHP project on a git server and I am working on local and there is a clone of it on the main server that my site is run on it.
I have two branches :
1.master
2.server

Now my question is:
How to make some changes on master and only merge some changes (not all) on the 'server' branch ?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
git cherry-pick commit-Id
```

for every commit you want to get from the other branch.

You can get the commit-Id from the output of

```
git log
```

See http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-cherry-pick.html for more information.